# What MIME media type (content type) should be used for Apache Parquet files?

Tags: http, hadoop, parquet

**BACKGROUND**: Apache Parquet is an open source, column-oriented data file format designed for efficient data storage and retrieval. It provides efficient data compression and encoding schemes with enhanced performance to handle complex data in bulk. Parquet is becoming a standard for large data operations and therefore should be stored and returned from web servers with a standard MIME type.

**QUESTION**: A system that supports MIME type storage is loading data into a cloud storage system, in Apache Parquet format, to be processed by Headless SQL or Hadoop, what MIME type should be provided for the ".parquet" files.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [discussion](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1889), `application/vnd.apache.parquet` is the [standard](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.apache.parquet) as of March, 2024.

```
(registered 2024-02-14, last updated 2024-03-05)
Media type name: application
Media subtype name: vnd.apache.parquet
Required parameters: N/A
Optional parameters: N/A
Encoding considerations: binary
```